# Filenet Invoke step get locked in fnsystem user

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine, content-platform-engine

I have a invoke step in my work flow that run and send the request to server and get the respond from it , but it get locked at this step to the "fnsystem" user

In information Stack it shows Queue as WSRequest(0) and Error Number 0x0 for invoke step (F_QueueWPClassId is "-9(WSRequest)")

**In process engine log it shows error of**

---

```
XXXX-XX-XXXXX:25:01.439 7BDFD491 ENG  FNRCE0001E - ERROR method name: XXXX/XX/XX XX:53:21.762+0530 CMDp.CRT7933 XXXXXXX DB=CXXXXXX Reg#2 [Error] FNRPE2131090405E CMExecute[913].XXXXX.CRXXXXX_2.WSRequest.fnsystem [XXXX_XXXXXBalanceStates:5C4XXX075XXB1C4EXXXXEF4A2C21XXX4:Workflow:Invoke] DISPATCH FAILED!; Exception: Unexpected exception -- see chained exception 

        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.throwTranException(DbTransaction.java:1103) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.HandleDistributedTransactionError(DbTransaction.java:678) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask._saveStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:573) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.dispatchStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:402) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.WSInvokeOperation.invoke(WSInvokeOperation.java:949) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.PEWSRequestAdaptor.execute(PEWSRequestAdaptor.java:105) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:161) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:145) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239) 
        at com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.doAs(UserContext.java:142) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.call(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:143) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:188) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.doMyJob(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:317) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.process(CMDispatcherTask.java:408) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.doMyJob(CMDispatcherTask.java:170) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMBaseTask.doJob(CMBaseTask.java:103) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.DelayBackgroundTask.run(DelayBackgroundTask.java:232) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:939) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:963) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790) 
    Caused by: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0001E: E_ACCESS_DENIED: The requester has insufficient access rights to perform the requested operation. failedBatchItem=0 errorStack={ 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.checkPropertyAccess(IndependentPersister.java:2365) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.checkUpdatePermissions(IndependentPersister.java:2072) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.preUpdate(IndependentPersister.java:1255) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.preExecuteChange(IndependentPersister.java:603) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.SubscribablePersister.preExecuteChange(SubscribablePersister.java:227) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.ReplicablePersister.preExecuteChange(ReplicablePersister.java:125) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.CmTaskPersister.preExecuteChange(CmTaskPersister.java:100) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.executeChangeWork(IndependentPersister.java:499) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.executeChange(IndependentPersister.java:333) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.SubscribablePersister.executeChange(SubscribablePersister.java:177) 
        at com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.executeChanges(RequestBrokerImpl.java:1487) 
        at com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.executeChanges(RequestBrokerImpl.java:1345) 
        at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineCoreBean._executeChanges(EngineCoreBean.java:619) 
        at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineCoreBean.executeChangesUT(EngineCoreBean.java:592) 
        at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EJSLocalStatelessEngineCore_22877cb1.executeChangesUT(Unknown Source) 
        at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineBean.executeChanges(EngineBean.java:909) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs.EJSRemoteStatelessEngine_2e64c374.executeChanges(Unknown Source) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs._Engine_Stub.executeChanges(_Engine_Stub.java:671) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl._executeChanges(EJBSession.java:861) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl.run(EJBSession.java:550) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl.executeChanges(EJBSession.java:599) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession.executeChanges(EJBSession.java:393) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle.executeChanges(SessionHandle.java:112) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callExecuteChanges(Session.java:184) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChanges(Session.java:570) 
        at com.filenet.api.core.UpdatingBatch.updateBatch(UpdatingBatch.java:168) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.CETransactionCache$FlushCEObjectsOnTransactionCommit.priorToCommitOp(CETransactionCache.java:228) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.ProcessPriorToCommitTranOpSet(DbTransaction.java:1229) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.executePriorToCommitOps(DbTransaction.java:584) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.EndDistributedTransaction(DbTransaction.java:522) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask._saveStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:566) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.dispatchStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:402) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.WSInvokeOperation.invoke(WSInvokeOperation.java:949) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.PEWSRequestAdaptor.execute(PEWSRequestAdaptor.java:105) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:161) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:145) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239) 
        at com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.doAs(UserContext.java:142) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.call(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:143) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:188) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.doMyJob(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:317) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.process(CMDispatcherTask.java:408) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.doMyJob(CMDispatcherTask.java:170) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMBaseTask.doJob(CMBaseTask.java:103) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.DelayBackgroundTask.run(DelayBackgroundTask.java:232) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:939) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:963) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790) 
    } 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor173.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.NoArgNewInstanceAction.run(NoArgNewInstanceAction.java:43) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:453) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.ExternalizableFactory.allocateNewExternalizableObject(ExternalizableFactory.java:62) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.FastPathForCollocated.deepCopy(FastPathForCollocated.java:240) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.ORBVM.deepCopyIfRequired(ORBVM.java:83) 
        at com.ibm.oti.vm.ORBVMHelpers.vmDeepCopy(ORBVMHelpers.java:206) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.VMDeepCopier.performDeepCopy(VMDeepCopier.java:229) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.FastPathForCollocated.writeNonStaticNonTransientFields(FastPathForCollocated.java:358) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:608) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.OutputStreamHook.defaultWriteObject(OutputStreamHook.java:133) 
        at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:321) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.FastPathForCollocated.invokeWriteObjectMethod(FastPathForCollocated.java:753) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.FastPathForCollocated.invokeWriteAndReadObjects(FastPathForCollocated.java:575) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.FastPathForCollocated.deepCopy(FastPathForCollocated.java:280) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ObjectCopierFactory$DeepObjectCopier.doWork(ObjectCopierFactory.java:327) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ObjectCopierFactory$AbstractCopier.waitForCompletion(ObjectCopierFactory.java:169) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ObjectCopierFactory$AbstractCopier.getCopy(ObjectCopierFactory.java:187) 
        at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil.copyObject(ProxyUtil.java:372) 
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl.copyObject(UtilDelegateImpl.java:861) 
        at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObject(Util.java:327) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs._Engine_Stub.executeChanges(_Engine_Stub.java:674) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl._executeChanges(EJBSession.java:861) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl.run(EJBSession.java:550) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl.executeChanges(EJBSession.java:599) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession.executeChanges(EJBSession.java:393) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle.executeChanges(SessionHandle.java:112) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callExecuteChanges(Session.java:184) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChanges(Session.java:570) 
        at com.filenet.api.core.UpdatingBatch.updateBatch(UpdatingBatch.java:168) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.CETransactionCache$FlushCEObjectsOnTransactionCommit.priorToCommitOp(CETransactionCache.java:228) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.ProcessPriorToCommitTranOpSet(DbTransaction.java:1229) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.executePriorToCommitOps(DbTransaction.java:584) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.EndDistributedTransaction(DbTransaction.java:522) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask._saveStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:566) 
        ... 24 more
XXXX/XX/XX XX:53:48.078+0530 CMDp.CRT7933 PEPrimary2 DB=XXXXXXX Reg#2 [Error] Exception during ISI processing work object XXXX2EBA46BDXXXXABCD3XXXX40; Exception: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0057E: E_READ_ONLY: The method failed because an object or property is read-only. Read-only property XXXX_XXXXdateStates cannot be updated. 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.checkSettable(PropertiesImpl.java:696) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.checkSettable(PropertiesImpl.java:666) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.putObjectValue(PropertiesImpl.java:356) 
        at filenet.jpe.expr.ExpressionEvaluator$ExprCEReferenceObject.setFieldValue(ExpressionEvaluator.java:246) 
        at filenet.jpe.definitions.AssignWorkOrder.evalExpr(AssignWorkOrder.java:340) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.executeOpAssign(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:4197) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.doAdvance(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:2746) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.doExecute(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:2042) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.advance(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:1004) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask._saveStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:556) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.dispatchStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:402) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.WSInvokeOperation.invoke(WSInvokeOperation.java:949) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.PEWSRequestAdaptor.execute(PEWSRequestAdaptor.java:105) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:161) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:145) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239) 
        at com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.doAs(UserContext.java:142) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.call(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:143) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:188) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.doMyJob(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:317) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.process(CMDispatcherTask.java:408) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.doMyJob(CMDispatcherTask.java:170) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMBaseTask.doJob(CMBaseTask.java:103) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.DelayBackgroundTask.run(DelayBackgroundTask.java:232) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:939) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:963) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
XXXX/XX/XX XX:53:48.079+0530 CMDp.CRT7933 PEPrimary2 DB=CRTOSDC Reg#2 [Error] ISI Exception (Wob  3E4EXXXX46BDCCC9ABCD38A7745); Exception: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0057E: E_READ_ONLY: The method failed because an object or property is read-only. Read-only property XXXX_XXXXdateStates cannot be updated. 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.checkSettable(PropertiesImpl.java:696) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.checkSettable(PropertiesImpl.java:666) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.putObjectValue(PropertiesImpl.java:356) 
        at filenet.jpe.expr.ExpressionEvaluator$ExprCEReferenceObject.setFieldValue(ExpressionEvaluator.java:246) 
        at filenet.jpe.definitions.AssignWorkOrder.evalExpr(AssignWorkOrder.java:340) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.executeOpAssign(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:4197) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.doAdvance(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:2746) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.doExecute(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:2042) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.advance(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:1004) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask._saveStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:556) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.dispatchStep(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:402) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.WSInvokeOperation.invoke(WSInvokeOperation.java:949) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.ws.PEWSRequestAdaptor.execute(PEWSRequestAdaptor.java:105) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:161) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker$1.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:145) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:196) 
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:153) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239) 
        at com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.doAs(UserContext.java:142) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.call(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:143) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask$TaskWorker.run(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:188) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMExecuteAStepTask.doMyJob(CMExecuteAStepTask.java:317) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.process(CMDispatcherTask.java:408) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMDispatcherTask.doMyJob(CMDispatcherTask.java:170) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMBaseTask.doJob(CMBaseTask.java:103) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.DelayBackgroundTask.run(DelayBackgroundTask.java:232) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:939) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:963) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
```

---

the invoke is a system step run by a fnsystem user and property "XXXX_XXXXdateStates" on all workflow steps & properties shows as read-write .
[image]

why this step failed at system stem to the "fnsystem" user even all steps and workflow definition properties shows it as read-write , any input is highly appreciated..

---

### EDIT

---

Note: "fnsystems" is in object store properties with all permission

[image]

[image]

I have replaced my property XXXX_XXXXdateStates with a new property because i was thinking maybe the access rights didn't inherit for my object store or roster.and i got same error (E_ACCESS_DENIED) for a system task(TaskState update) with a system property (LastFailureReason)

```
2018/XX/XX XX:XX:XX.252+0530 CMRX.CRXXA4X PESecondary1 [Error] FNRPE2131090405E fail to move wob 87D6770XXX34194XXX7A3D2 to exception submap Malfunction; Exception: Unexpected exception -- see chained exception 

        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.throwTranException(DbTransaction.java:1103) 
        at filenet.jpe.database.DbTransaction.HandleDistributedTransactionError(DbTransaction.java:678) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMRecoveryTask.doMyJob(CMRecoveryTask.java:135) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMBaseTask.doJob(CMBaseTask.java:103) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.common.DelayBackgroundTask.run(DelayBackgroundTask.java:232) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:939) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:963) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790) 
    Caused by: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0001E: E_ACCESS_DENIED: The requester has insufficient access rights to perform the requested operation. failedBatchItem=0 errorStack={ 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.checkPropertyAccess(IndependentPersister.java:2365) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.checkUpdatePermissions(IndependentPersister.java:2072) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.preUpdate(IndependentPersister.java:1255) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.preExecuteChange(IndependentPersister.java:603) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.SubscribablePersister.preExecuteChange(SubscribablePersister.java:227) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.ReplicablePersister.preExecuteChange(ReplicablePersister.java:125) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.CmTaskPersister.preExecuteChange(CmTaskPersister.java:100) 
        at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.executeChangeWork(IndependentPersister.java:499)

 XXXX/XX/XX 14:23:57.255+0530 CMRX.CRTCA47 PESecondary1 DB=CRTXXXX Reg#2 [Error] Wob  EBAE2XXXXX8D4AA750XXXF4AB476, Exception on TaskState update (Work Performer Exception: LOCK TIMEOUT).; Exception: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0057E: E_READ_ONLY: The method failed because an object or property is read-only. Read-only property LastFailureReason cannot be updated. 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.checkSettable(PropertiesImpl.java:696) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.checkSettable(PropertiesImpl.java:666) 
        at com.filenet.apiimpl.property.PropertiesImpl.putValue(PropertiesImpl.java:370) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.TaskStateUpdater.reallySetException(TaskStateUpdater.java:183) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.TaskStateUpdater.setException(TaskStateUpdater.java:108) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.callExceptionIS(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:3669) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.doAdvance(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:2304) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.doExecute(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:2042) 
        at filenet.jpe.server.isi.InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.advance(InstructionSheetInterpreterClass.java:1004) 
        at filenet.jpe.cm.CMRecoveryTask.doMyJob(CMRecoveryTask.java:129)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that something is wrong with your security setup. The error has nothing to do with access rights on the workflow map or those to the workflow definition. The system tries to update `Content Engine` object associated with the running workflow instance and fails to do so. System `fnsystem` account cannot get required access to that object.

You should verify that `fnsystem` is granted access to the object store and related objects (normally this happens by default). You should also check whether you have various security facilities like security policies or marking sets in place. They might prevent normal access to objects.

If this does not help, you should verify that `CPE` is installed and configured properly. [Creating Content Platform Engine directory server accounts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.planprepare.doc/p8ppi078.htm) is a place to start.

Comment: i add a edit for post , i have no security policies , solution work in my test and UAT environment ok ,only production give this error. fnsystem was in object store as in edit. i have a separate object store in production running with out errors even with invokes (but cant put in that becouse property limit in docversion table ), so error can it be CPE ? . seems access rights dont get inherited.highly appreciated you input fnt..

Comment: The fact that this works in another object store only confirms the cause is in its configuration. Either something prevents access to that object (as I have already noted) or the property is simply read-only. You should check effective access rights on that CE object associated with failing workflow instance.

Comment: do you mean Component Queue in acce ? CE object's Component Queue in Workflow System is added with p8admin and have all solution's roles in security . i will check this again anyways...

Comment: I know nothing about your data model, but from the stracktrace it is clear that PE tries to synchronize some data to CE. In IBM Case Manager, for example, there is a corresponding object in CE for each workflow instance.